# glGenVertexArrays and glDeleteVertexArrays not resolved for Windows

Tags: ios, windows, cocos2d-iphone, bridge, winobjc

I am trying to port iOS projects to Windows 10 using Windows Bridge for iOS.
But I am stuck to the unresolved functions of `glGenVertexArrays`, `glBindVertexArray`, and `glDeleteVertexArrays`.

The original iOS project is a Cocos2d 2.x project. I am not familiar with OpenGL, Therefore I ask for help here! Thank you!

By the way, I noticed that the same issue also exists if I paste these functions into the sample project of WOCCatalog.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Searching the repo for "glGenVertexArrays" does not return anything. Therefore, this API (along with tons of others) is not yet implemented.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. 
I am not sure if these functions need implementation. Maybe they require including necessary libs only in the project property section.
Are you sure searching the repo is sufficient to find out the reason of this issue? ^0^

Comment: If it's just a typedef, it should work if you implement it manually. If it's a procedure, then it probably needs a windows implementation. Just linking an iOS library shouldn't work.

Comment: It seems to me that these functions have not been implemented. Thank you any way!